# Can I publish a book and source code in the book under different licenses?

Tags: copyright, licensing

Can I publish a book and the source code in the book under two different licenses?
Eg. Publish a book under the GNU FDL license, but license the source code examples in this book under the Apache license?

Comment: Books are not generally licensed.  Did you see a license in your copy of *Green Eggs and Ham*?

Comment: What about "Free as in Freedom" by Richard Stallman?

Comment: It is very common for some free publications to be licensed under a free license like CreativeCommons.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you own the copyright to the works, you can even publish the [source code itself under two different licenses](http://www.linuxinsider.com/story/38172.html), which can be radically different. For example, [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/about/legal/licensing/foss-exception/#3) is licensed under both a commercial and an open-source license.

Given that you can publish a single piece of work as multiple licenses, it is your choice which one you wish to grant to the book or the code, as long as you own the copyright.